# Partitioning Problem

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu with windows . I deleted two partitions to install ubuntu . After I installed ubuntu  these drive still keep on showing in windows . What should I do so that these do not appear in windows

Comment: If possible can you post a screenshot?  Even better if you go to the Disk Manager in Windows and post the view of these 'rogue' partitions from there

Comment: I cannot . It's The reputatuon thing over here and I am a newbie over here

Comment: You should be able to post a link to a screenshot though; use something like imgur.com to host the image itself.

Comment: i deleted F and J first and then installed ubuntu in them but they keep on showing 
[link](http://i.imgur.com/87yAgYb.png)
[link](http://i.imgur.com/beNwOAe.png)